# Whats new for list.asmx in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

i am using 2007 list.asmx for updating listitem from a third party application, is there any substitute now in sp 2013

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The asmx web services have been deprecated. Use the REST API instead.

[Lists and list items REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433%28v=office.15%29.aspx)